# Help configure multiple network interfaces

Tags: networking, vpn, interface, virtualization, routing

I'm running Ubuntu inside a VM on my work laptop. I have to run my VPN software on my VM Host system and need access to my VPN network from within my Ubuntu VM.

I can set my VM's network interface to NAT and this takes care of my VPN connectivity issues. I can reach any host inside my work interface via the NAT interface.

In addition to my VPN needs, I would like hots on my LAN to connect to my VM. For example, I want to run a NFS server on my VM that another host on my LAN wants to connect to. (Note -- I don't want a remote VPN host to connect to my VM).

To allow this, I added a second Bridge network interface to my VM. This works fine and I can reach my VM from any other host on my LAN.

The *problem* with enabling both interfaces is that the NAT interface (VPN) is no longer used, so my VPN hosts becomes unreachable.

I've tried altering the VMWare settings so that the NAT interface is eth0 and Bridged interface is eth1 and vice-versa without any luck.

I assume I need to do something with my routing table to tell Ubuntu to route anything to 192.168.99.255 (my LAN) with ethX and everything else through ethY.

How do I set these rules up? Can I do this via the network connections gui?

---

Output of route -n is below.
192.168.99.0 is the bridged interface (LAN), .222.0 is the NAT interface.

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.99.1    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0
192.168.99.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0
192.168.222.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth1
```

Comment: I'd contact VMWare directly.

Comment: Why? Isn't this a Ubuntu network manager configuration issue?

Comment: What does the output of  `route -n` look like with both adapters enabled?

Comment: @bigbash I added the output to the original question. Code blocks don't seem to work in comments

Comment: @KZ. Are you using VMware Workstation or VMware Player?  

Also, does  your work VPN subnet overlap with your local LAN? ie both are 192.168.1.x


I was able to reproduce your issue and fix it but I'll need those details first.

Comment: @bigbash I am using VMware workstation. I am not sure I'm following your question exactly. Both subnets have Mask:255.255.255.0.

Comment: @KZ. What I am asking is you work network the same as 192.168.99.x?  If not what is your work network?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9902/discussion-between-bigbash-and-kz)

Comment: @bigbash 192.168.99.X is my LAN with subnet mask 255.255.255.0, and my work interface is a 10.255.255.255 subnet -- I'm assigned a 10.1.50.x IP. I can reach various 10.x.y.z IPs. 

The VM host system is also connected to the 192.168.99.X (i.e. my router).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VMware Workstation goto `Edit > Virtual Network Editor` then click on VMnet8 which should be your NAT adapter.

Then click on NAT settings, this will bring up a menu that will tell you what your NAT adapter gateway is (you will need that).

Once you have that you will need to then add a static route for your VPN subnet like so:

`route add -net 10.1.50.0 netmask 255.0.0.0 gw 192.168.222.2`

The syntax is:

`route add -net $WORK-NETWORK netmask $NETMASK gw $NAT-ADAPTER-GW`

Both networks should now be reachable from the VM.

If you want to add the route so it persists upon reboot you will then need to edit `/etc/network/interfaces` and add

```
# static route
post-up route add -net 10.1.50.0 netmask 255.0.0.0 gw 192.168.222.2 dev eth1
```