# How does a computer decide which network interface to send traffic to?

Tags: routing, ethernet

I have a computer (Ubuntu) with one wired and one wireless network interface. The wired one is statically assigned and connected to another single machine with a statically assigned address. The wireless is connect to an AP and has an IP address assigned by DHCP and access to the internet. How can I make sure that all requests go out on the wifi interface except if it's a specific IP address then I want that to go out on the wired connection?

Comment: +1 - hopefully the friendly neighborhood NESE mods will move it over there (and the OP will get more Ubuntu-specific tips for accomplishing this!)

Comment: When I get home, I'll figure out the right place to migrate unless Craig or YLearn do it first...

Comment: Thanks, happy to have it moved over there instead if that's a better place for it.

Comment: Q bigbash is referring to [is here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/327047/help-configure-multiple-network-interfaces) it is slightly different, and a few minutes of my searching on AU didn't give me a similar Q... so migrating to AU.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add a static route on your host with next-hop set to an exit interface (your wired interface).

Example:

```
route add -host <insert the specific ip here> dev eth0
```

Assuming `eth0` is the interface name of your wired interface.

EDIT:

If you want these to persist across reboots, you'll have to modify your `/etc/network/interfaces` to something like this:

```
... (other pertinent stuff)
post-up route add -host <insert specific ip> dev eth0
```

Ideally to your `eth0` (or whatever the wired interface label is) configuration.